# Destructuring props in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-props

I have a problem troubleshooting EsLint error
 `ESLint: Must use destructuring props assignment (react/destructuring-assignment)`.
The linter requires destructuring the props, but if I do that, I get an undefined parameter.
In my code, I am trying to get a parameter from a URL.
What am I doing wrong?

Here I indicate what parameters should be in the URL:

```
<Route path="/confirm-register/:userName?" component={ConfirmRegistrationPage} />
```

My original code, it works as expected, the `userName` parameter gets a string value:

```
strong textconst ConfirmRegistrationPage = (props) => {
  const { userName } = props.match.params;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Congratulations, {userName}! </h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

What I have tried. In this case, userName is undefined:

```
strong textconst ConfirmRegistrationPage = ({ userName }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Congratulations, { userName }! </h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

eslint settings:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
    "eslint-config-airbnb"
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 11
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "react/jsx-filename-extension" : "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "import/no-named-as-default": "off",
    "import/no-named-as-default-member": "off",
    "react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to destructure `props.match.params` => `props` is an *object* with a `match` property that  is an *object* with a `params` property which is an *object* that has a `userName` property. So it'd be `const ConfirmRegistrationPage = ({ match: { params: { userName } } }) => {...}` Read this [article](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f) for a nested object destructuring example.

Comment: @MattCarlotta This solution works. True, it seems to me that this is strange. Anyway, thanks for your solution.

Comment: Or you could just turn off the rule. `const { userName } = props.match.params;` makes for easier reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit props destructuring. I would choose the first variant. Its more readable.

```
// first variant 
strong textconst ConfirmRegistrationPage = ({ match }) => {
    const { userName } = match.params
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Congratulations, { userName }! </h1>
        </>
    );
};

// second variant
strong textconst ConfirmRegistrationPage = ({ match: { params: { userName } } }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Congratulations, { userName }! </h1>
        </>
    );
};

// third variant
strong textconst ConfirmRegistrationPage = ({ match: { params } }) => {
    const { userName } = params
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Congratulations, { userName }! </h1>
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Here's a simple tutorial explaining [how to destructure props in react with hooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mlNBuIAtFY)

Comment: if the property is more than 2, do you prefer destructuring or no?